# Trouble rendering graph as dictionary with lists in sets in Python 2 vs 3

Tags: python

This is a 2 parter.

The following code is in Python 2. It renders a graph as a dict with values as sets containing lists.

```
import urllib2

CITATION_URL = "http://storage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-alg/alg_phys-cite.txt"

def load_graph(graph_url):

    graph_file = urllib2.urlopen(graph_url)
    graph_text = graph_file.read()
    graph_lines = graph_text.split('\n')
    graph_lines = graph_lines[ : -1]

    print "Loaded graph with", len(graph_lines), "nodes"

    answer_graph = {}
    for line in graph_lines:
        neighbors = line.split(' ')
        node = int(neighbors[0])
        answer_graph[node] = set([])
        for neighbor in neighbors[1 : -1]:
            answer_graph[node].add(int(neighbor))

    return answer_graph
```

Sample output: {1001: set([9304045, 9308122]), 1002: set([9201007, 9204031, 9210123, 9912187]), ... }

The above code was updated for Python 3. The part responsible for rendering the graph remained unchanged:

```
answer_graph = {}
for line in graph_lines:
    neighbors = line.split(' ')
    node = int(neighbors[0])
    answer_graph[node] = set([])
    for neighbor in neighbors[1 : -1]:
        answer_graph[node].add(int(neighbor))

return answer_graph
```

Sample output: {9306112: {9210128, 1, 9202065}, 9306114: {1, 9204065, 9301122} ...}

1) Why did the node: set([1, 2, 3]) notation disappear even though it was embedded in the code?

2) I tried changing `answer_graph[node].add(int(neighbor))` to `answer_graph[node].add([int(neighbor)])` to get the list to appear within the set. I got the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. This is a point of **extreme** confusion for me at the moment. I've seen posts on here that suggest sets can't contain lists. This is manifestly false, as I've represented graphs this way. That said, it just threw an error at me when I tried to add a list to a set.

What am I missing with respect to these two questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way how sets are printed in Python 2 and 3. The set of 3 elements `1, 2, 3` is printed in Python 2 as

```
set([1, 2, 3])
```

and in Python 3, it is printed as

```
{1, 2, 3}
```

So `set([9304045, 9308122])` is the set of two elements `9304045, 9308122`, not the set with the list `[9304045, 9308122]` as an element.